# React Material UI: useResizeContainer - The parent DOM element of the data grid has an empty width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, width, reduce

The table (normal DataGrid of MUI, not pro version) I am trying to display should have the exact summed up width all columns (maybe plus 10px). Apart from that the table should be centered in its parent div.
The error I am getting is:

`MUI: useResizeContainer - The parent DOM element of the data grid has an empty width. Please make sure that this element has an intrinsic width. The grid displays with a width of 0px.`

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: 'Job id', headerName: 'Job id', colId:'Job id', width: 150 , sortable:true, editable:false, type:'text', align:'center',headerAlign: 'center'},
    { field: 'Name', headerName: 'Name', colId:'Name', width: 80, sortable:true, editable:false, type:'text', align:'center',headerAlign: 'center'},
    { field: 'User', headerName: 'User', colId:'User', width: 80, sortable:true, editable:false, type:'text', align:'center',headerAlign: 'center'},
    { field: 'Time Use', headerName: 'Time Use', colId:'Time Use', width: 90, sortable:true, editable:false, type:'text', align:'center',headerAlign: 'center'},
    { field: 'S', headerName: 'S', colId:'S', width: 50, sortable:true, editable:false, type:'text', align:'center',headerAlign: 'center'},
    { field: 'Queue', headerName: 'Queue', colId:'Queue', width: 80, sortable:true, editable:false, type:'text', align:'center',headerAlign: 'center'},

  ]

const columnWidths = columns.reduce((acc, column) => {
    return acc + column.width;
  }, 0);
  
const containerStyle = {
margin: '10px auto',
maxWidth: columnWidths + 10,
};
return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: 10, display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <div style={containerStyle}>
        <DataGrid
            columnBuffer={6}
            disableVirtualization
            density='compact'
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            getRowHeight={({ id, densityFactor }) => {
                return 30 * densityFactor;
                }}           
            disableSelectionOnClick   
            hideFooter={true}
            rowBorder ={false}
            disableColumnFilter ={true}
            disableColumnMenu={true}

                {...rows}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

```
const columnWidths = columns.reduce((acc, column) => {
    return acc + column.width;
  }, 0);
  
const containerStyle = {
margin: '10px auto',
maxWidth: columnWidths + 10,
};
```

This correctly sums up the width and provides a container for the DataGrid displaying the table correctly.

But this also produces the above error. The proposed methods were

columnBuffer={6} > did not change anything

disableVirtualization > did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

```
const containerStyle = {
  margin: '10px auto',
  maxWidth: columnWidths + 10,
  width: columnWidths + 10,
};
```

The width attribute helps